# Where would one fish in Andoran?

Tags: golarion

I just read about there being a fishing festival in Andoran, called Silverglazer Sunday. Yet, it doesn't look like there would be that many places to fish besides the southern coast. The one lake I know about is Droskmere within the Darkmoon Wood... but that's hardly a safe place to bring many people to party, is it?

Would the few rivers of the region be the only other choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, looking at [a large scale Golarion map](http://www.mapsofgolarion.com/), seeing Andoran and saying "looks like there's nowhere to fish except the coast and those rivers" is like looking at any large scale map of the USA and saying "looks like you can only fish on the coast, rivers, or Great Lakes." Use Google Maps for clarification. At [this level of detail](http://goo.gl/maps/9YRqd) Colorado looks like a land-locked no-water kind of place, but googling for Colorado fishing festivals garners several; zoom in to understand why.

The scale is obscuring a large number of smaller scale topographical features, including the nearly ubiquitous smaller waterways and ponds needed to sustain life. As you zoom in, there's more. [Here's an example of a map of Darkwood Vale in Andoran](http://www.myth-weavers.com/showthread.php?t=50984) - just as in real life, more rivers, ponds, etc. appear. Pretty much anyplace depicted as being a non-desert with arable farmland will have a rich set of natural waterways - rivers, lakes, creeks, streams, ponds, etc.

RPG products aren't designed to give you every micro-feature of an entire country.  To cheat, use existing maps and almanacs.  The Inner Sea is similar to the Med. Andoran is about where Greece/Albania/Macedonia/Bulgaria is geographically. So if your guys are near Carpenden, a likely geographical analogue - scrolling about to find somewhere not so mountainous - let's say [here](https://goo.gl/maps/Cl4J6). Then you decide Carpenden is maybe analagous to [Stavrochori](https://goo.gl/maps/t5c8e). Keep zooming in to find other features, use them as they lay and/or as you prefer!

Comment: Hmm, a good point! I don't know that there are more maps detailing other regions of Andoran, so maybe I'll have to make up lakes here and there.